# Redis.blPop: How check how many process wait 'key'?

Tags: redis, phpredis

I am use PhpRedis

$redis->blPop('key', 10);

How check how many process wait 'key'?

$redis->blPop**CountWait**('key'); => 30

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that in Redis.

The closest you can get is running `CLIENT LIST` and filter the reply by 'cmd=blpop', but this will not tell you the actual key(s) each connection is blocking on.